# 'src' module not found

Tags: import, module

I have this code that I switched from PyCharm to Visual Studio Code.
I get the followin error on imports when I try to execute the mainbox.py file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\2xProjects\Python\UtilityBox\src\utilitybox\mainbox.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.utilitybox.auxiliar import reusable_functions
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Code:

```
import os.path

import customtkinter as ctk

from src.utilitybox.auxiliar import reusable_functions
from src.utilitybox.auxiliar.configure_log import LogConfigurer


__all__ = []



class MainBox(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        # Main windows specifications
        super().__init__()
        self.button_click = None
        self.title(' Utility Box')
        self.geometry('850x430')
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.configure(bg='#222629')
        self.window_already_open = False
        self.toplevel_window = None
        self.numberentries = 0
        self.after(250, lambda: self.iconbitmap(
            os.path.join(reusable_functions.get_project_icons_path(), 'Main.ico')))

        self.operation_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, width=172, height=400, corner_radius=20,
                                            border_width=1, border_color='#474B4F')
        self.operation_frame.grid_propagate(False)
        self.operation_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=15, pady=(13, 0))

        self.search_button = ctk.CTkButton(self.operation_frame, text='Search', font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'),
                                           fg_color='#00539C', text_color='white',
                                           command=lambda: self.create_search_window())
        self.search_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=(13, 0))

        self.sort_button = ctk.CTkButton(self.operation_frame, text='Sort', font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'),
                                         fg_color='#00539C', text_color='white',
                                         command=lambda: self.create_sort_window())
        self.sort_button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=0, pady=(15, 0))

        self.delete_button = ctk.CTkButton(self.operation_frame, text='Delete', font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'),
                                           fg_color='#00539C', text_color='white',
                                           command=lambda: self.create_delete_window())
        self.delete_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=0, pady=(15, 0))

        self.encryption_button = ctk.CTkButton(self.operation_frame, text='Data Protection',
                                               font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'), fg_color='#00539C', text_color='white',
                                               command=lambda: self.create_data_protection_window())
        self.encryption_button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=0, pady=(15, 0))

        self.preview_button = ctk.CTkButton(self.operation_frame, text='Archives', font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'),
                                            fg_color='#00539C', text_color='white',
                                            command=lambda: self.create_archive_window())
        self.preview_button.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=(15, 0))

        self.clear_log_button = ctk.CTkButton(self.operation_frame, text='Clear log', font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'),
                                              fg_color='#00539C', text_color='white',
                                              command=self.button_click)
        self.clear_log_button.grid(row=8, column=0, pady=(145, 0))

        self.log_frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(master=self, width=580, height=360, corner_radius=20,
                                                border_width=1, border_color='#474B4F')
        self.log_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=15, pady=(13, 0))

    # Create each window from
    def create_search_window(self):
        from src.utilitybox.frames.search_window import SearchWindow
        if self.toplevel_window is None or not self.toplevel_window.winfo_exists():
            self.toplevel_window = SearchWindow(self)
        else:
            self.toplevel_window.focus()

    def create_sort_window(self):
        from src.utilitybox.frames.sort_window import SortWindow
        if self.toplevel_window is None or not self.toplevel_window.winfo_exists():
            self.toplevel_window = SortWindow(self)
        else:
            self.toplevel_window.focus()

    def create_delete_window(self):
        from src.utilitybox.frames.delete_window import DeleteWindow
        if self.toplevel_window is None or not self.toplevel_window.winfo_exists():
            self.toplevel_window = DeleteWindow(self)
        else:
            self.toplevel_window.focus()

    def create_data_protection_window(self):
        from src.utilitybox.frames.data_protection_window import DataProtectionWindow
        if self.toplevel_window is None or not self.toplevel_window.winfo_exists():
            self.toplevel_window = DataProtectionWindow(self)
        else:
            self.toplevel_window.focus()

    def create_archive_window(self):
        from src.utilitybox.frames.archive_window import ArchiveWindow
        if self.toplevel_window is None or not self.toplevel_window.winfo_exists():
            self.toplevel_window = ArchiveWindow(self)
        else:
            self.toplevel_window.focus()

    def update_log(self, log_message: str, specific_operation_color: str) -> None:
        """
        Updates the logging frame box with the message given.

        Parameters:
            log_message (str): The log message to be displayed.
            specific_operation_color (str): The color for displaying the log message.

        Returns:
            None
        """
        log_text = ctk.CTkTextbox(master=self.log_frame, width=565, height=20, corner_radius=20,
                                  fg_color=specific_operation_color,
                                  font=('Helvetica', 14, 'bold'))
        log_text.grid(row=self.numberentries, column=0, pady=(0, 10), sticky='w')
        log_text.insert(ctk.END, log_message)
        self.numberentries += 1


def check_log_folders() -> None:
    """
    Create logging folders if they do not exist.

    This function initializes the Log Configurer and checks for the year, month, and category folders.
    If any of these folders are missing, it creates them.

    Returns:
        None
    """
    log_configurer = LogConfigurer()
    log_configurer.check_and_create_year_folder()
    log_configurer.check_and_create_month_folder()
    log_configurer.create_category()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainbox = MainBox()
    mainbox.mainloop()
```

And got this file generated:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Tree of the project:
[Project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SsDN.png)

This might sound stupid but I really don't understand, the path should be clear and the module is present in my project.

Thank you for your help and time :)

Comment: importing and modules in python is just not easy to understand. I'd recommend playing around with modifying where you run the project from. My guess is vscode is for some reason running the actual python entry script from some other location than pycharm, that could result in errors such as this